# getting permissions in

Tags: permissions

I am trying to load new brushes in "krita" but all I get is a dialogue box saying "extraction not preformed you don't have the right permissions to extract archives in the folder "krita". 
I tried to edit them by going to properties but all dialogue boxes are greyed out, Help.I am running 14.04 on an HP 64 bit.norm

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
sudo nautilus
```

In a terminal. This will launch nautilus (your file explorer) as root and then you should be able to change the permissions as you want but be careful!

Comment: I'm not sure if just changing the permissions, without investigating what they're *supposed* to be first, is the best way to proceed. But if this method is to be used, it is preferable to run `gksudo nautilus` or (if the `gksu` package that provides the `gksudo` command is not installed), `sudo -H nautilus` or `sudo -i nautilus`. See [Why user should never use normal sudo to start graphical application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application)

Comment: Yes are right about investigating the permissions the file is supposed to be, the problem is probably somewhere else but sometimes a quick solution is wanted.
I wasn't aware of the problems of the use of `sudo` to start a graphical application thank you.